# How do I take the sum of sublists in a main list?

Tags: python

I have list which holds 24,389 values and they are subdivided into lists of 29 values each. So, the main list contains 841 sublists.

I've squared each element in every sublist and I want to sum up the elements of each individual sublist.

For example a sublist like

```
[1,2,3] , [4,5,6]
```

should give me the sum [6,15]

However, the code I have used tries to take the sum of all the sublists and because it is a really big number at the end, it just displays NAN.

this is the code;

```
def square(number):
    return number ** 2

squaring_iterator = map(square, numbers)
squared_numbers = list(squaring_iterator)
print(squared_numbers)

Sum1 = sum(squared_numbers)
#print(Sum1)
final2 = [Sum1[i * n:(i + 1) * n] for i in range((len(Sum1) + n - 1) // n )]
print(final2)
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: You can just map `sum` over the list: `list(map(sum, your_list))` the same way you did `square`.

Comment: So your big list looks something like this? `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]...]` If so, @Mark's comment should work.

Comment: What is your data type and how you display it? Which ide? Python can deal with very very very large number. Try to `print(100**100)` first!

Comment: @Michael My numbers were in the range of about 10^10 and 10^11 and I had about 24,000 of them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [sum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) function and a comprehension list expression

```
your_list = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]] 
new_list = [sum(l) for l in your_list]
print(new_list)
```

Output:

```
[6, 15]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using numpy:

```
import numpy as np
lst = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]
sum_of_nums = np.array(lst).sum(1) # sums all elements in the sublists
print(sum_of_nums)
```

```
Output: [6, 15]
```

Answer (score 0):

#### If you cant fix it, please provide your entire code.

##### Below is my code

---

sample 1

```
from time import time
from random import randint


def square(number):
    return number ** 2


start_time = time()


data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]


n = 3
numbers = [data[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(data), n)]
print(len(numbers))

# 2


squared_numbers = [[square(_) for _ in sub] for sub in numbers]
print(squared_numbers)

# [[1, 4, 9], [16, 25, 36]]


final = [sum(s) for s in squared_numbers]
print(final)
[14, 77]


final2 = sum(final)
print(final2)

# 91


print(f'total time:{(time()-start_time)}')

# total time:3.0994415283203125e-05
```

---

### when `randint(10**100, 10**101)`, it only spent `1.1 sec.`, with `print()`!

sample 2

```
from time import time
from random import randint


def square(number):
    return number ** 2


start_time = time()


data = [randint(10**10, 10**11) for _ in range(24389)]


n = 29
numbers = [data[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(data), n)]
print(len(numbers))


squared_numbers = [[square(_) for _ in sub] for sub in numbers]
print(squared_numbers)


final = [sum(s) for s in squared_numbers]
print(final)


final2 = sum(final)
print(final2)

# 89543746479132138668264091

print(f'total time:{(time()-start_time)}')

# total time:0.13712477684020996
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
np.sum(np.array(your_list), axis=1)
# or
np.sum(your_list, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
array([ 6, 15])
```